# AngularJS ng-repeat through json array doesnt work in second array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do a ng-repeat over a json array. I'm able to do the first iteration of 'event in calendar'. But I'd not have to manually iterate through each number.
This works:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in calendar">
          {{event[0].custom_fields.location[0]}}
          {{event[0].custom_fields.price[0]}}
          {{event[1].custom_fields.location[0]}}
          {{event[1].custom_fields.price[0]}}  
          {{event[2].custom_fields.location[0]}}
          {{event[2].custom_fields.price[0]}}        
</div>
```

I've tired doing two ng-repeats and it fails. How do I fix this?

```
<div ng-repeat="event in calendar">
          <div ng-repeat="custom_fields in event.custom_fields">
             {{custom_fields.location[0]}}
             {{custom_fields.price[0]}}
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 3):

According to your first example, event is the array, not the custom_fields property.  Iterate it instead.

```
<div ng-repeat="events in calendar">
    <div ng-repeat="event in events">
        {{event.custom_fields.location[0]}}
        {{event.custom_fields.price[0]}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont have "events", only "event"

Comment: @SeanWinkler You're misunderstanding how the locally scoped variables will work.  events is just a variable created to hold the result of the calendar iterations.